# Redirect User based on page template used

Tags: php, wordpress, function

i have wordpress blog. I use different templates for blog posts and medical cases. I installed plugin for creating custom templates per post and it do their job. But now want medical cases to be available just for logged in users.
Page that i want to manage is using my custom template:

[image]

So i search in google for function that will limit [access by template](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) and by logged in status. And writen this function:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );
function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if ( is_page_template( $template = 'templates/clinic_case.php' ) && is_single() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'url/wp-login.php', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

but when try to load, content is loading just fine, and should not. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that by the time Wordpress processes your code, it has already passed the *template_redirect* [hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).